# Is there specification for Go's lifetime model of allocated memory?

Tags: go

Go uses escape analysis and garbage collection to manage memory allocation on stack and heap. [Go's FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#stack_or_heap) also says:

> **How do I know whether a variable is allocated on the heap or the stack?**
>
> From a correctness standpoint, you don't need to know. Each variable in Go exists as long as there are references to it. The storage location chosen by the implementation is irrelevant to the semantics of the language.

So Go allocates a memory for a variable, and reserves it at least until it's needed.

My question is: Is this (abstract) behavior written in [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)? I found the allocation part is written, for example, in [Allocation section](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Allocation):

> The built-in function `new` takes a type `T`, allocates storage for a variable of that type at run time, and returns a value of type `*T` pointing to it.

But is there any description of the reservation part? Can we confirm the fact "Each variable in Go exists as long as there are references to it"? If not, is there any reasons?

For example, I want to confirm the following program must not throw SIGSEGV or similar exceptions if a Go compiler has no bugs.

```
func foo() *int {
    x := 42
    return &x
}
func main() {
    px := foo()
    fmt.Println(*px)
}
```

To be more precise, I expected that the two part, "Go allocates memory when `new` or something" and "Go reserves the allocated memory at least it's needed", should be written in the specification. I don't care about its implementation details, even though https://github.com/golang/go uses escape analysis and garbage collection.

If the latter part does not exist, then in an extreme case, it's valid implementation according to the spec that the memory is un-allocated immediately after it is allocated. But this is ridiculous, so I think the spec should invalidate that.

<sub>Edit for close: I don't think this question is opinion-based. This question is a simple yes/no-question, asking for the description in the specification. The reason for the existence/non-existence can be answered with citations. If not, please show/comment which points are opinion-based. I'll improve that.</sub>

Comment: In the [Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go) doc: "Note that, unlike in C, it's perfectly OK to return the address of a local variable; the storage associated with the variable survives after the function returns."

Comment: If it collected variables that still had references, Go programs wouldn't work.

Comment: @JimB I know Effective Go also mentions that, but it is not a specification.

Comment: @Adrian Indeed. But it's should be written in the specification even if it's ridiculous.

Comment: @nekketsuuu: because how things are allocated is an implementation detail, and the implementations should work correctly however they choose to implement things.

Comment: @JimB I don't say the implementation details should be written in the spec. I want to confirm the allocated memory must be held if needed, but not how to implement that feature.

Comment: The specification doesn't _have_ to spell out facts which do not need be mentioned. The language specification doesn't _require_ an implementation to use garbage collection. If you read the spec carefully the whole idea of GC is only mentioned once in the _introduction_, but not a single word in the spec describes how to GC stuff. You could have a Go compiler which doesn't collect at all. Or use reference counting or whatnot. You are _constructing_ a problem.

Comment: I think he is just looking for the place in the spec where it says that he can count on pointer indirection always giving the value stored in the referenced variable. It is a valid question.

Comment: @Volker You may be misunderstanding my question. To be more precise, I don't want escape analysis and GC should be mentioned in the spec. Instead, I expected the lifetime of the allocated memory should be written in the spec. I'm not worried about the implementation details, but I'm worried about behavior around memory.

Comment: From the spec: "Calling the built-in function new or taking the address of a composite literal allocates storage for a variable at run time." The memory is allocated and from the point of the spec never "freed". You cannot describe the "lifetime of allocated memory" because from the spec's point there _is_ no "lifetime". The whole concept of "freeing" memory doesn't exist in the spec. You cannot describe that memory is not "freed" or "unallocated" while variables still point to that memory without _having_ a notion of "freeing". Releasing/freeing/collection _is_ an implementation detail.

Comment: @Volker Yes, AFAIK the spec does not mention about free-ing. Then we cannot confirm we can safely use the allocated memory. So I asked this question. In an extreme case, it's valid implementation along to the spec even if free the memory just after allocating it. But this is ridiculous, so I think the spec should invalidate that.

Comment: "Then we cannot confirm we can safely use the allocated memory." Why? What if the following would be added to the specification: "Memory which is allocated can be used." Would that satisfy your needs? Or would that trigger a follow up question like "Where in the spec is written down that the spec is not _lying_? How are we supposed to safely follow a spec which might be lying?"

Comment: @Volker I want the spec describes "Memory which is allocated can be used *at least until when?*" I want the spec says "Each variable in Go exists as long as there are references to it" as the FAQ does.

Comment: The spec is open source and the project even accepts Github merge requests. If you think this sentence (replace "reference" with "pointer" as reference has a different meaning in the spec) needs to be added: Give it a try!

Comment: @Volker Thanks for your suggestion =) In fact, I asked this question to confirm there is no mention about un-allocating before submitting an issue or a pull request. Thanks for letting me know there is no description and discussing why.

Comment: Lifetime is covered at the end of the [section on variables](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables):  The specification uses the term *variable* for storage location. A variable's value is retrieved by referring to the variable in a expression. If a variable can be referenced, then the value can be retrieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specification uses the term *variable* for storage location. The specification does not distinguish between storage locations on the heap or the stack. The terms *heap* and *stack* are absent from specification.

The [section on variables](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variables) says:

> A variable's value is retrieved by referring to the variable in an expression; it is the most recent value assigned to the variable. If a variable has not yet been assigned a value, its value is the zero value for its type.

If a variable can be referenced, then the variable's value can be retrieved. The compiler and runtime must retain a variable's value when there are extant references to the variable.

Comment: +1: Also for a no-name storage location which is referenced by a pointer (like `*px` in my example), the spec uses a term "anonymous variable": "Such an anonymous variable is referred to via a (possibly implicit) pointer indirection." Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

> But is there any description of the preservation part? Can we confirm the fact "Each variable in Go exists as long as there are references to it"? If not, is there any reasons?

Not in the language specification, no; that is a quality of the runtime, not the language. We can confirm the fact that memory is not collected as long as there are references to it by simply observing that Go programs actually work. If that assumption were not valid, most of the standard library would be invalid, along with pretty much all code written by any Go developer. The Go compiler's escape analysis and garbage collector definitely work.

The FAQ entry you found is canonical and can be relied upon, same as the spec.

Comment: The specification does indeed say that you must always be able to deference pointers, unless they are nil.

Comment: @AndreasVinter-Hviid where? "Dereference" appears in two places in the spec, neither makes this guarantee.

Comment: See my answer. It says that `*x` denotes the variable pointed to by `x` unless `x` is nil. It is not called "dereference" by the spec though. It is called pointer indirection. So maybe I should not have used that term.

Comment: @Adrian Thank you for your answer, but I think this is not a problem of runtime. Also, I don't worried about a bug of implementation, but worried about a bug of the spec. See my edit of the question.

Comment: I agree that the FAQ is as famous as the spec, but I think the spec should be self-contained.

Comment: @nekketsuuu see the first sentence of my answer. The spec is the **language** spec. Memory management is a quality of the runtime, not the language. The spec also doesn't describe the scheduler or garbage collector, because those too are qualities of the runtime.

Comment: So do you think how long the memory is (at least) allocated is not important for semantics of the language? I believe it should be written in the spec because if not, some ridiculous implementation is valid (see question). Also some other languages defines that in its spec. For example, C defines "storage durations" in its specification.

Comment: Beliefs are irrelevant on SO. What C does is irrelevant to Go. If you disagree with what is or isn't included in the spec, you should take that up with the maintainers.

Comment: So I asked this in SO to confirm it actually does not exist in the spec. Thanks, I'll make an issue on golang/go.

Comment: The spec says that variables contain the last value assigned to them, and that these variables can be accessed through pointers to them. These statements are not qualified in any way meaning that they always must hold. To me it is pretty clear that the spec guarantees the lifetime of any variable to be the entire duration of the program.

Comment: @AndreasVinter-Hviid Would you please let me know where the spec says that, like [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61502242/is-there-specification-for-gos-lifetime-model-of-allocated-memory#comment108808402_61502242)? That is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score -2):

The thing that you could imagine would cause an issue is the `*px` in the main function. If the thing pointed to by `px` does not exist any more. However, According to this section: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators

> For an operand x of pointer type *T, the pointer indirection *x denotes the variable of type T pointed to by x. If x is nil, an attempt to evaluate *x will cause a run-time panic.

This basically says that an implementation of Go is bound to give you the value pointed to, unless the pointer is `nil` in which case it will panic. The specification does not say how an implementation is to do this, but you can count on any implementation of Go doing this some how.

This matches what your first quote says.

Comment: "This basically says that an implementation of Go is bound to give you the value pointed to" no, it says it's bound to cause a panic if it is `nil`. The quote doesn't make any guarantees of what happens when it is not `nil`.

Comment: It does. When `x` is not `nil`, `*x` is the variable pointed to by `x`. A variable is by the spec a storage location which holds a value.

Comment: "`*x` denotes the variable of type T pointed to by x" does not make any guarantee of what *happens* when you dereference it, only what the syntax `*x` *means*.

Comment: The spec is not operational at all. It says that `*x` means the variable pointed to by `x`. It also says that a value can be retrieved from a variable. A correct Go implementation must respect this. A correct Go implementation cannot just decide to segfault when it runs into a pointer indirection, because pointer indirection is defined for *all* pointers and never defined to segfault.

Comment: The conclusion is correct. But memory management is not *explicitly* defined in the spec; heap/stack allocation, GC behavior, and escape analysis are implementation-specific details that are left up to the compiler. The spec does not say how long a value lives in memory; it only implies it.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with your last comment. I am not saying that the details of how memory is managed is set in the spec. I am just saying that the spec guarantees that a variable can always be referenced indirectly through a pointer to it.